# Flutter Integrate Apple pay response to stripe

Tags: flutter, mobile, stripe-payments, applepay

Unhandled Exception: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, message: No such payment_intent: 'pi_3M9vFfDn3WtZLRhzO5kP10SM', stripeErrorCode: resource_missing, declineCode: null, type: invalid_request_error))

I hit apple pay then after payment , reverted to stripe payment intent and then I get client secret from response . I revert that response to Stripe for payment verification and I got response as No such payment_intent or getting payment method reuired

@ᴅ ᴇ ʙ ᴊ ᴇᴇ ᴛ and @orakaro here is what I done

```
Future<void> onApplePayResult(paymentResult) async {
debugPrint("paymentResult.toString() is ${paymentResult.toString()}");
var data = jsonDecode(paymentResult['token']);
debugPrint("data is $data");
String transactionId = data['data'];
var response = await PaymentService().makePayment(
         context: context,
         amount: 100
            ,
        );
String clientSecret = response['client_secret'].toString();
final params = PaymentMethodParams.cardFromToken(
         paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodDataCardFromToken(
       token: token,
     ));
await Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(
       "clientSecret",
       params,
     );
}
```

Comment: You need to be clearer on your question, and the context of your integration. What integration path/Doc are you using? Why do you create a PaymentIntent after ApplePay?

Generally "No such payment_intent" the PaymentIntent belongs to a different Stripe Account than the one you are using the Publishable Key of

Comment: Share your PaymentIntent code and have you enabled apple pay ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I m using apple pay and successfully retrieved token from apple pay and then hitting stripe without opening payment sheet with amount which I paid using apple pay

Comment: Where I need to enable Apple pay in Xcode or Stripe

Comment: Please guide me to fix this urgent

Comment: If I pay via Apple pay present on Stripe payment sheet then I m getting error as

 {
  "error": {
    "message": "The certificate used to sign your request is invalid. For help troubleshooting, please visit https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/apps#troubleshooting.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_UHgF15TCajfEPL?t=1669887576",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ᴅ ᴇ ʙ ᴊ ᴇᴇ ᴛ and @orakaro here is what I done , I edit my question please let me know